# How to load Request Desktop Mode Site for iPAD

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, youtube

IPad on the YouTube page, I want to open in the desktop mode. But somehow it did not.

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"https://www.youtube.com";
//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
//URL Requst Object
NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
[requestObj setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"UserAgent"];


//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[web loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Maybe try changing the `requestObj` so it mimics a desktop system, it's set as mobile currently. (eg. `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A`)

Comment: tried but didnt work :(

Comment: The only other immediate suggestion would be make sure you clear the cache, etc.

Comment: cleared the cache. same problem continues.

Comment: Not sure it'll make a difference, but try changing `UserAgent` to `User-Agent`... also consider using `[requestObj setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]` (or GET) before `[web loadRequest...]`

Comment: GET and POST again tried it did not. Is there another way you know?

Comment: The way you've done it seems correct; without seeing the actual headers returned it hard to know why not.